# How to validate plain object with class-validator?

Tags: object, nestjs, class-validator

So I have a DTO:

```
@IsBoolean()
someBool: boolean

@IsString()
someStr: string

???
someObject: any
```

How do I validate someObject? Its value is a plain JS object, just some arbitrary JSON data, so it's NOT another DTO. It seems to me I'm supposed to create a custom validator / decorator in this case. Is this correct?
Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done using just JSON. You have to create a class type and use that as follows:

```
@IsBoolean()
someBool: boolean

@IsString()
someStr: string

@ValidateNested()
@Type(() => SomeClass)
someObject: SomeClass
```

And in SomeClass you also add validation decorators to the props.